# Getting a child's name as well as the value in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase Database I have data laid out as such:

```
paidRecord[
    John Smith: UNPAID
    Bill Smith: PAID
    Mary Smith: UNPAID
]
```

I am trying to create a String in my app that will display the paid status of all the people. At the moment all I have is a String that displays "UNPAID PAID UNPAID" but what I need is to display the users names as well.

Here is the function:

```
private void checkPaidStatus(){

    paidString = "";


    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Flats").child(flatID).child("Bills").child(itemSelected).child("paidRecord").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot != null){
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterable = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

                //this is the bit that needs to be changed to return properly xd good luck
                for (Iterator<DataSnapshot> it = iterable; it.hasNext();){

                    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 = it.next();
                    paidString = paidString + "new" + dataSnapshot1.getValue(String.class);
                    textViewPaidStatus.setText(paidString);

                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

So, is there a way on Firebase Database to return not only the value assigned to a key, but the key itself as well?

Comment: Can you show your current code? "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: The key is available from `DataSnapshot.getKey()` that is passed into your callback.

Comment: as frank says, please update your question with the code you have tried to get your values and we will assist you

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your key is also available in your sub-DataSnapshot just you need to get like bellow

```
DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 = it.next();
paidString = paidString + "new" + dataSnapshot1.getValue(String.class);
textViewPaidStatus.setText(paidString);
String mStrkey=dataSnapshot1.getKey()
```